# Jquery bind Focus Event to class dynamically in below condition

Tags: jquery, css

I am having HTML code as below,

```html
<div id="testDiv">
    <input id="testTxt" type="textfield" class="test" />
</div>
```

```js
$(".test").on("focus",function(){
    alert("hello")
});

('#testTxt').remove();

('#testDiv').html("<input id='testTxt' type='textfield' class='test' />");
```

I have created a simple textfield and bind focus event after that i want to remove that textfield and add new textfield code in that div with same class name but that focus event how to apply on that textfield in newly added textfield so that i can see alert.

Comment: You have some syntax errors; The last two selectors are missing the `$` prefix and have mis-matched quotes.

Comment: oh i am sorry i missed that here in my condition i want to bind focus event to newly created textfield is it possible in any way ? thank you so much for your effort

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).on("focus", ".test",function () {
    alert("hello")
});
$("#testTxt").remove();
$("#testDiv").html("<input id='test' type='textfield'class='test'/>");
```

Try this

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/brkjov80/)

Comment: @HUM glad to help happy coding